# Using boost::thread in a planet simulator

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I am making a simulator of planets in space, and the issue is, that I cannot simulate more than ~100 planets, because the simulation slows down exponentially. To solve this problem, I thought using threads could solve my problem, since I am probably not experienced enaugh to use graphic card processors to calculate.

I have 2 functions in my program wich are used to calculate the gravitational force between planets and another one to check for collisions. I implemented threads in a way, so I calculate gravitational forces in one thread and collisions in another.

The problem is that the simulation isn't running any faster then without using threads. Maybe I'm implementing them wrong?

```
int main()
{
    int numOfPlanets;
    cout << "Enter the maximum number of planets to generate: ";
    cin >> numOfPlanets;
    App.Create(sf::VideoMode(1366, 740), "SFML Galaxy Simulator");
    App.Clear(sf::Color(20,20,20));

    generateRandomPlanets(500, 500, numOfPlanets);
    //createPlanet(planets, sf::Vector2f(500,500), sf::Vector2f(0,0), 5, 500);

    thread thread_1;
    thread thread_2;


    while(App.IsOpened())
    {
        sf::Event Event;
        while (App.GetEvent(Event))
        {
            if (Event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
                App.Close();
        }

        App.Clear(sf::Color(20,20,20));
        thread_1 = thread(checkCollision);
        thread_2 = thread(calculateForce);
        thread_1.join();
        thread_2.join();
        updatePlanets();
        App.Display();
    }
    thread_2.join();
    thread_1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't think that *just bringing threads* could improve the performance here... Think in terms of data structures and algorithms. You might need to do structural changes to prepare the app for parallel execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    thread_1 = thread(checkCollision);
    thread_2 = thread(calculateForce);
    thread_1.join();
    thread_2.join();
    updatePlanets();
```

This launches two new threads to do some work in parallel, then blocks waiting for them to finish, then afterwards runs `updatePlanets`.  You probably want:

```
    thread_1 = thread(checkCollision);
    thread_2 = thread(calculateForce);
    updatePlanets();
    thread_1.join();
    thread_2.join();
```

This will run the three functions in parallel.

Also, this is an error at the end of `main`:

```
thread_2.join();
thread_1.join();
return 0;
```

You've already joined the threads, you can't join them again.

There's actually no point in declaring `thread_1` and `thread_2` outside the loop and reusing them, you could just declare them in the loop:

```
    thread thread_1(checkCollision);
    thread thread_2(calculateForce);
    updatePlanets();
    thread_1.join();
    thread_2.join();
```

Also be aware that if `updatePlanets` throws an exception it will terminate your program because the `thread_2` destructor will run while the thread is joinable and so call `terminate()`, which may be OK in this program, but is something to bear in mind.

Comment: Even after doing as you told, there is still no difference in performance

Answer (score 1):

I have made some more research after posting the question and found out that the main problem in the performance of my simulation was the time complexity of the algorithm for calculating gravitational forces of each planet relative to all other planets which was `O(n^2)`.

I found out, that one or maybe the best method to approach this is by using [Barnes-Hut](http://arborjs.org/docs/barnes-hut) algorithm for n-body simulation with it's time complexity of `O(n log n)`. The way this algorithm works is it divides all the planets into quadtree nodes and then calculates forces acording to the center-mass of each node.

So to add all this together, using Barnes-Hut algorithm together with threading is the best way to approach this problem.